# How to deal with instable second in dataframe datetime column to get minutely data?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, lubridate

I have to make data minutely from raw data which is instable second.
I can't use `second()` from `data.table` package to make it minutely from instable second with first half of minute being round down and the second half round up. It's not the good way with more and more raw data, it doesn't work well.

Here is my example data frame :

```
library(data.table)
df <- read.table(text="
             datetime   ,val
2019-06-19 08:25:55.470,1706506
2019-06-19 08:24:55.560,1706504
2019-06-19 08:24:07.087,1706502
2019-06-19 08:22:55.510,1706500
2019-06-19 08:22:00.080,1706497
2019-06-19 08:21:44.977,1706495
2019-06-19 08:19:55.533,1706493
2019-06-19 08:18:55.470,1706491
2019-06-19 08:18:17.610,1706488
2019-06-19 08:16:55.567,1706486
2019-06-19 08:15:55.440,1706484
2019-06-19 08:14:55.543,1706481
2019-06-19 08:13:55.427,1706479
2019-06-19 08:13:06.477,1706477
2019-06-19 08:12:21.043,1706475
2019-06-19 08:10:55.420,1706473
2019-06-19 08:09:55.447,1706471
2019-06-19 08:08:55.477,1706469
2019-06-19 08:07:55.443,1706467
2019-06-19 08:06:55.550,1706465",sep=",",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$datetime)
```

After made it straight minutely, It came out bad :

```
> minute(df$datetime[second(df$datetime) > 30]) = minute(df$datetime[second(df$datetime) > 30]) + 1
> second(df$datetime) <- 0
> df
              datetime     val
1  2019-06-19 08:26:00 1706506
2  2019-06-19 08:25:00 1706504
3  2019-06-19 08:24:00 1706502
4  2019-06-19 08:23:00 1706500
5  2019-06-19 08:22:00 1706497
6  2019-06-19 08:22:00 1706495
7  2019-06-19 08:20:00 1706493
8  2019-06-19 08:19:00 1706491
9  2019-06-19 08:18:00 1706488
10 2019-06-19 08:17:00 1706486
11 2019-06-19 08:16:00 1706484
12 2019-06-19 08:15:00 1706481
13 2019-06-19 08:14:00 1706479
14 2019-06-19 08:13:00 1706477
15 2019-06-19 08:12:00 1706475
16 2019-06-19 08:11:00 1706473
17 2019-06-19 08:10:00 1706471
18 2019-06-19 08:09:00 1706469
19 2019-06-19 08:08:00 1706467
20 2019-06-19 08:07:00 1706465
```

08:20:00 - 08:22:00 fail

Any help would be appreciated!

Edited : here is more raw data CSV link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aV14fwOHQw7ceTzaP5uNjPVO_MSN0cr_/view?fbclid=IwAR37Hoie4MT4eoo97_PF006hEoa7pxEWbnZQMPrcv3wFsOTuu7qiBunxfbw)

Comment: Why do you say it fails? Don't you want to round to the nearest minute?

Comment: @sindri_baldur missing and duplicate minute

Comment: This is unclear. What is the expected output for these rows?

Comment: The source rows are `08:22:00.080` and `08:21:44.977`, therefore `08:22` as result  for both makes sense, right?

Comment: I want row 6 should be `6  2019-06-19 08:21:00 1706495` because it might be recording device problem from late uploading data to database server. It records minutely and the value from this row is from `08:21:00`

Comment: The device records correctly minutely but late uploading a bit to server. I also don't have this device to fix the problem. I am just end user of this database table. sorry for bad grammars.

Comment: So what is it that makes you identify row 6 and not, say 15, as incorrect?

Comment: the distance between each val during this hour should be 2 to 3 from `> diff(df$val)
 [1] -2 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -3 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2` and row 6 is correct to be `08:21:00`

Comment: `2019-06-19 08:22:00.080` `2019-06-19 08:21:44.977` diff 16 seconds can't get the distance val by 2-3. it would be just 0-0.75 . Sorry for unclear explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I think you are after.

Even though I'd recommend reviewing the source data.

```
library(data.table)

DT <- fread(text="
             datetime   ,val
2019-06-19 08:25:55.470,1706506
2019-06-19 08:24:55.560,1706504
2019-06-19 08:24:07.087,1706502
2019-06-19 08:22:55.510,1706500
2019-06-19 08:22:00.080,1706497
2019-06-19 08:21:44.977,1706495
2019-06-19 08:19:55.533,1706493
2019-06-19 08:18:55.470,1706491
2019-06-19 08:18:17.610,1706488
2019-06-19 08:16:55.567,1706486
2019-06-19 08:15:55.440,1706484
2019-06-19 08:14:55.543,1706481
2019-06-19 08:13:55.427,1706479
2019-06-19 08:13:06.477,1706477
2019-06-19 08:12:21.043,1706475
2019-06-19 08:10:55.420,1706473
2019-06-19 08:09:55.447,1706471
2019-06-19 08:08:55.477,1706469
2019-06-19 08:07:55.443,1706467
2019-06-19 08:06:55.550,1706465", sep=",", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DT[, datetime := as.POSIXct(as.character(round(as.POSIXct(datetime), "mins")))]
DT[, diff := c(-60, diff(datetime))]
DT[diff == 0, datetime := datetime-60][, diff := NULL]
print(DT)
```

---

Result:

```
               datetime     val
 1: 2019-06-19 08:26:00 1706506
 2: 2019-06-19 08:25:00 1706504
 3: 2019-06-19 08:24:00 1706502
 4: 2019-06-19 08:23:00 1706500
 5: 2019-06-19 08:22:00 1706497
 6: 2019-06-19 08:21:00 1706495
 7: 2019-06-19 08:20:00 1706493
 8: 2019-06-19 08:19:00 1706491
 9: 2019-06-19 08:18:00 1706488
10: 2019-06-19 08:17:00 1706486
11: 2019-06-19 08:16:00 1706484
12: 2019-06-19 08:15:00 1706481
13: 2019-06-19 08:14:00 1706479
14: 2019-06-19 08:13:00 1706477
15: 2019-06-19 08:12:00 1706475
16: 2019-06-19 08:11:00 1706473
17: 2019-06-19 08:10:00 1706471
18: 2019-06-19 08:09:00 1706469
19: 2019-06-19 08:08:00 1706467
20: 2019-06-19 08:07:00 1706465
```

Comment: Thanks and upvoted, it works well with the example but not the whole raw data. Could you please review this CSV from this link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aV14fwOHQw7ceTzaP5uNjPVO_MSN0cr_/view?fbclid=IwAR37Hoie4MT4eoo97_PF006hEoa7pxEWbnZQMPrcv3wFsOTuu7qiBunxfbw)

Comment: Please update the question with some of the lines causing the issue instead.

Comment: `500 2019-06-19 08:20:00 1706493` `501 2019-06-19 08:22:00 1706495` `502 2019-06-19 08:21:00 1706497` `503 2019-06-19 08:23:00 1706500` found datetime switching (minute:20-19-21-23) after tried with 1054 rows. Should I just sort datetime?

Comment: it looks good after sorted only datetime column but not sure it would cover all cases. anyways, thank you so much.